# Problem running express app with pm2 using ecosystem config file

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

When I run my Node.js express app using `node` command everything works fine!
When using `pm2 server`./bin/www` my pm2 status is something like this:

[image]

And my app works in this situation. Also when I use `pm2 start bin "./bin/www" -i 0` my `pm2 list` shows:

[image]

And yet again my app works. But using following config file:

```
module.exports = {
apps: [{
        name: 'cdn',
        script: './bin/www',
        instances: 0,
        exec_mode: 'cluster',
        watch: true,
        env: {
            NODE_ENV: 'production',
            PORT: process.env.PORT || '5555',
             }
       }]
};
```

the application while listening on the specified port does not work and prints no error messages and my pm2 status is:

[image]

How should I use config file correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you forgot `.config.js` in your ecosystem filename.

I lost hours of my day looking for the exact same problem yours and a ignored line of pm2 [docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) alerts me what I forgot (a weird requirement).

> Note that using a Javascript configuration file requires to end the file name with .config.js

Comment: Thanks. May be you are right but unfortunately this question is for months ago and I cannot check your solution!

Comment: Not a problem.
Someone can reach your question as I and this answer may be helpful!